# Facebook login is working with release APK before publishing App, but not after publishing same APK

Tags: android, facebook-login

### Facebook login is working with release APK before publishing App, but not after publishing same APK in Play Store.

I am trying to implement **Facebook Login** into my app from past 2 days. I have followed all the steps and added both key-hash (for **debug** and **release**) into my app at facebook developer account.

Its working fine with **both type of build variant** before publishing app in Play Store, but after downloading same release variant (which I am testing before publishing app) from Play Store, Facbook Login is not working.

One more thing is that Facebook Login is not working only if Facebook app is installed in device. If App is not installed, its working fine with web view.

I have used below code to get debug and release key-hash by changing build variants in android studio:

```
try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.my.package.name", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    }
```

[My app is available for public in Facebook developer account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qftSO.png)

I am not getting what I am doing wrong or what I am missing. Please help !

Your help will be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not going use suffix for package names?

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am using my app package name instead of "com.my.package.name"

Comment: I got it but just thought if you are using some build scripts that suffix or changes your package name. This is only thing that came to my mind. Sorry :(

Comment: Also you know every machine has different debug certificate unless you are not signing with given debug certificate?

Comment: No problem. I will check again for this and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the app is published, Google make a new fingerprint for your apk. Add the new fingerprint. It might work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Play store only provides MD5, SHA-1 and SHA-256 certificates but not provides 28 characters long key hash according to my research.
Please let me know if I am correct or I am missing anything.

Comment: You may develop 28 character hash-key using the key. Have a look here http://www.androidauthority.com/add-facebook-and-twitter-auth-to-your-app-757722/

Comment: Great Man ! Finally Its working. I did't found anything related to converting play store SHA-1 fingerprints on given link but I converted it to 28 characters key-hash manually as per your comment... And there is no problem now. Than you.......

Answer (score 0):

### Solved

I have **converted SHA-1 certificate fingerprints provided by play store to 28 characters key-hash for facebook login** using below method:

```
// Play Store App Signing SHA-1 Key (Example):- 9A:B0:98:16:76:23:B5:9A:55:83:00:FF:76:0E:B6:B9:C6:FE:A3:C7
    byte[] sha1KeyHash = {(byte) 0x9A, (byte) 0xB0, (byte) 0x98, (byte) 0x16, (byte) 0x76, (byte) 0x23, (byte) 0xB5, (byte) 0x9A, (byte) 0x55, (byte) 0x83, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0x76, (byte) 0x0E, (byte) 0xB6, (byte) 0xB9, (byte) 0xC6, (byte) 0xFE, (byte) 0xA3, (byte) 0xC7};
    System.out.println("keyHashForFacebookLogin: " + Base64.encodeToString(sha1KeyHash, Base64.NO_WRAP));
```

I have used this key-hash in my facebook developer account..

And **its working perfectly..**

Comment: use this link for converting SHA1 to hash key
http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en

Comment: @BasavarajWalikar Output (base64): result is key-hash?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same way that Harendra S Nayal, converting the sha1 from Play Store to key-hash. I share the code in kotlin.

First I created the function

```
    fun byteArrayOfInts(vararg ints: Int) = ByteArray(ints.size) { pos -> ints[pos].toByte() }
```

After

```
// Play Store App Signing SHA-1 Key (Example):- 9A:B0:98:16:76:23:B5:9A:55:83:00:FF:76:0E:B6:B9:C6:FE:A3:C7
    val sha1KeyHash = byteArrayOfInts(
            0x9A, 0xB0, 0x98, 0x16, 0x76,
            0x23, 0xB5, 0x9A, 0x55, 0x83,
            0x00, 0xFF, 0x76, 0x0E, 0xB6,
            0xB9, 0xC6, 0xFE, 0xA3, 0xC7)

    Log.d("TAG","keyHashForFacebookLogin: " + Base64.encodeToString(sha1KeyHash, Base64.NO_WRAP));
```