# Facebook login doesn't work if app is downloaded from google play

Tags: android, facebook, google-play, react-native, facebook-login

we have a problem with our app. The problem is that facebook login stops working if the app is downloaded from google play. If I install this app on a device from the command line or I download it from AppCenter, then facebook login working. The signature keys are the same. Does anyone know where the problem might be?

We have used this package https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk but the version 0.9.0 and we have more apps when the facebook login working.

Comment: have you used the keyhash generated from release key store ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook login is working with release APK before publishing App, but not after publishing same APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46430280/facebook-login-is-working-with-release-apk-before-publishing-app-but-not-after)

Comment: yes, I have used the key hash generated from the release key store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your Google Play Console > Your Project > Release Management > App Signing > Copy SHA-1 certificate fingerprint and paste it in your facebook console in the SHA-1 field.

Or follow this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17770788/5773044

Answer (score 0):

It is because it  might have only the sha key of debug mode of your app.You need to add the sha key of release version of your app in facebook console.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, guys. I try to convert the SHA-1 key to base64 and paste it to the facebook app.

Comment: hi, is it convert the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint from app signing certificate from google play console to base 64 then copy to key hashes in facebook console?